# Can you keep an API that's pointing at an AWS Fargate managed container app exposed without paying to keep the container running permanently?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-fargate

**Details**

I need to permanently expose an API. I will be doing this using a simple `node.js Express` app running in a `Docker` container managed by `AWS ECS`.

The endpoints exposed by the app's API have to be constantly available, although cold starts won't be a problem so I am happy to spin up a container from scratch per request.

**My Actual Question**

In order to keep the costs down, I was wondering if it's possible to keep the API exposed via an `AWS ALB` and have the requests routed to the Docker container, but have the request wait to be handled until the container has been spun up? So, in essence, the container is sleeping between requests.

**Extra Context**

I cannot use `API Gateway` and `Lambda functions` for this as the payload is too large (over 10mb) for `API Gateway` to handle, and I cannot use a pre-signed URL from S3 because the inbound request is going to be a POST request of content-type `application/json` which means that it cannot be handled by pre-signed S3 URLs.